# Пытаю запустить Visual Studio Kernel Debugger на удаленной машине

Tags: visual-studio, kernel, виртуальная-машина

Пытаю запустить Visual Studio Kernel Debugger на удаленной машине.

Сталкиваюсь с ошибкой:

```
[HRESULT 0x800706BE] A failure occurred while running a test operation: 'DriverTestTasks::_DriverPreparation'. (The process hosting the test code was unexpectedly terminated with exit code 0xC0000409 while invoking a test operation.)
File: , Line: -1
Error Type:
Error Code: 0x0
Error Text: Error 0x00000000
Error   9.30.2020 12:58:01.542
DriverTestTasks::_DriverPreparation
Result: Fail
```

Comment: А это не может быть ошибкой авторизации?

Comment: Нет, драйвер в итоге собирается. Но отладчик не запускается.